# NLTK CFG recursion depth error

Tags: python, nltk

```
import nltk   
from nltk.parse.generate import generate,demo_grammar   
from nltk import CFG   
grammar = CFG.fromstring("""   
ROOT -> S
S -> NP VP
NP -> NP PP
NP -> DT NN
DT -> 'The'
NN -> 'work'
PP -> IN NP
IN -> 'of'
NP -> DT NN
DT -> 'the'
NN -> 'painter'
VP -> VBZ ADJP
VBZ -> 'is'
ADJP -> JJ
JJ -> 'good'
""")    
print(grammar)   
for sentence in generate(grammar, n=100):   
   print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Gives an error

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Tried changing covert function in functools.py, still the same issue.

Comment: See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/7

Comment: Saw the post. So the issue persist till date, is it?

Comment: It's not a problem with the library. It's a problem with how you defined your grammar. Do you see the part that goes into infinite loop in your grammar?

Comment: I tried the example in that forum and saw the comments and wnt through this quote "And possibly, the "linguistic" solution would be to include the NP -> N N rule (but it has to be the first rule before NP -> N NP:" Well I was not expecting my code  to go into infinite loop would adding and recoding  NP -> N NP solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `generate`, as its docstring states, "Generates an iterator of all sentences from a CFG." Clearly it does so by choosing alternative expansions in the order they are listed in the grammar. So, the first time is sees an `NP`, it expands it with the rule `NP -> NP PP`. It now has another `NP` to expand, which it also expands with the same rule... and so on ad infinitum, or rather until python's limits are exceeded.

To fix the problem with the grammar you provide, simply reorder your first two `NP` rules so that the recursive rule is not the first one encountered:

```
grammar = CFG.fromstring("""   
ROOT -> S
S -> NP VP
NP -> DT NN
NP -> NP PP
DT -> 'The'
...
""")
```

Do it like this and the generator will produce lots of complete sentences for you to examine. Note that the corrected grammar is still recursive, hence infinite; if you generate a large enough number of sentences, you will eventually reach the same recursion depth limit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Why don't the occurrence of NP... N...gets numbered, it also seems to solve the issue

Comment: What do you mean, "numbered"? Any rule that avoids infinite recursion right away will "solve" the issue. I showed how to do it without changing the rules of your grammar. (Understand that the corrected grammar still produces an infinite generator; it just returns finite-length sentences first).

Answer (score -1):

I tried to number the repeating occurrence of NP NN DT etc. It seems to solve the problem due to unique identification( I presume). What wonders me is it should have been like this at first place i.e the tree production thrown out should have serialized the parts of speech.

```
import nltk   
from nltk.parse.generate import generate,demo_grammar   
from nltk import CFG   
grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
ROOT -> S   
S -> NP VP
NP -> NP1 PP
NP1 -> DT1 NN1
DT1 -> 'The'
NN1 -> 'work'
PP -> IN NP2
IN -> 'of'
NP2 -> DT2 NN2
DT2 -> 'the'
NN2 -> 'painter'
VP -> VBZ ADJP
VBZ -> 'is'
ADJP -> JJ
JJ -> 'good'
""")    
print(grammar)   
for sentence in generate(grammar, n=100):   
   print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Comment: Linguistically, you're overspecifying rules, e.g. there seems to be no good motivation for DT1 and DT2, why not `DT -> 'The' | 'the'`. When unspecifying rules work, it's elegant. When overspecification is necessary, it's usually a "hack" ;P

Comment: It's not necessary and it's not correct. Your change turned a recursive grammar into a finite one: You can no longer have two `PP`s in an NP, for example. Spend some time thinking about what a CFG expresses, and play with it with paper and pencil.

Comment: @ Alexis I respect your point of view. I need to study CFG in depth before going for make shift solutions, which in this case is counter productive to the recursive cause.